# How to add event listener on month change event in an ion-datetime object?

Tags: javascript, ionic6

If I use an ion-datetime object and select a date. I can retrieve the value of the selected date with the event: ionChange.

```
var element = document.getElementById('My-ION-DATETIME');
element.addEventListener('ionChange', function (event) {    
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail.value));
    
    var dateFormat = event.detail.value.split('T')[0];
    alert(dateFormat);

}, false);
```

On the other hand, if I change the month using the arrows < or > or if I slide the page to change the month, how can I trigger an event with the month value and the year value that is displayed after month change ?

Many thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to another month or year you need to select some value there to trigger ionChange. In other words, this is the event which is triggered when new value is selected and not when you viewing different period(s).

Comment: this doesnt fix the issue